# How to create a SOBEL shader?

Tags: shaders

I've been curious as to how recreate the sobel (edge detection) node from the compositor into the shader editor.
It seems the general method consists to create an highpass image and then use a mixmode in overlay as shown in this [video>>](https://youtu.be/zdoDACeAxhQ)
The general technical sobel method is described [here>>](https://youtu.be/uihBwtPIBxM)
And [from this page](https://www.projectrhea.org/rhea/index.php/An_Implementation_of_Sobel_Edge_Detection) it would seem, separate XYZ with an offset would be the way to go.

So far this is how close I've come to creating this at shader level:
[image]

Please help as to what could be the correct approach to recreate a sobel filter detection at shader level.
Thanks!